# Unable to drop unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I have a table that contains Unique key on of the columns. How do I delete the unique key from the that column. I am using Sql Server 2008

When I use the following command I get error

```
ALTER table [Contact].[FatcaQuestionaire] 
DROP CONSTRAINT  UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact
```

'UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact' is not a constraint.

Comment: please add a tag with your RDBMS.

Comment: tried this but says incorrect syntax

Comment: ALTER table [Contact].[FatcaQuestionaire] 
DROP INDEX [Contact].[FatcaQuestionaire].UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact

Comment: @Tom [`DROP INDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176118.aspx) is not part of `ALTER TABLE` - it stands alone.

Comment: I even tried the following but says incorrect syntax ALTER table [Contact].[FatcaQuestionaire] 
DROP INDEX UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact on [Contact].[FatcaQuestionaire]

Comment: the syntax for dropping the index should be `drop index UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact`

Comment: I get the message Cannot drop the index 'Contact.FatcaQuestionaire.UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

Comment: are you using management studio?

Comment: Hi Slim ghost if I remove the table name I get message Must specify the table name and index name for the DROP INDEX statement.

Comment: yes i am using management studio

Comment: `SELECT * FROM  sys.objects WHERE name = 'UK_FatcaQuestionaire_Contact'`.. does this return any records ?

Comment: Use SSMS to script out the dropping of the object, then try executing it in SSMS.